# Swift - Class and dictionnary - Long Data

Tags: class, swift, dictionary

I use the following class and dictionary. The problem I have is that I get limited by the length and XCode does not allow me to give more then 180 references for my restaurant:

```
class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var restaurants:[Restaurant] = [

Restaurant(name: "le", type: "the", location: "Le printemps est de retour", image: "a001.jpg", isVisited: "Spring is back", sound: "1", image2: "1.jpg"),   
Restaurant(name: "de", type: "of", location: "Un verre de vin", image: "a002.jpg", isVisited: "A glass of wine", sound: "2", image2: "2.jpg"),   
Restaurant(name: "un", type: "a", location: "Un ticket de bus", image: "a003.jpg", isVisited: "A bus ticket", sound: "3", image2: "3.jpg") ....
}
```

My question is: How can I expand my dictionary ? I have a thousand reference that I want to put in a table so people can pick the one they want.

I hope my question make sense otherwise I can clarify.

Comment: Can you add the error you get when you're trying to instantiate this array?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810625/xcode-beta-6-1-and-xcode-6-gm-stuck-indexing-for-weird-reason or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360748/swift-app-takes-6-minutes-to-build. The Swift compiler has problems with "large" expressions. You could read the data from a file (e.g. JSON) instead.

Comment: @Joel, I do not have any error but Xcode chunk the data ... when I place 300 or more restaurants references, it trim the data to 186 or something. I was thinking about adding dictionary but did not find the declarations type ...

Comment: @martin, ok thank you, I'm going to check it out

Comment: anyone else? Thank you ;)