# Reading Data From a Text File with Swift

Tags: swift

For example I have a list of some items in a text file. I want to read that data one by one. How can I do that in Swift? I've found `NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(path)` but this reads whole file. In C++ i was using ifstream for that. Example:

```
ifstream fd(fileName);
    string code, type, title;
    int price, date;
    getline(fd, title);
    while (!fd.eof()) {         
        getline(fd, code, ',');
        fd >> ws;
        getline(fd, type, ',');
        fd >> ws;
        fd >> date;
        fd.ignore();
        fd >> price;
        fd.ignore();
    }
    fd.close();
```

And sample text file for that:

```
Title of List
K123, document, 1994, 12500
S156, photo, 2006, 7000
R421, book, 1998, 6000
```

How can I read files with Swift like that and get words in it one by one?

Comment: This might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581517/read-a-file-url-line-by-line-in-swift, even it it addresses your question only partially. – Also it *is* possible to call the BSD library functions `getline()` and `getdelim()` from Swift.

Comment: `getdelim()` might be useful for that. I will try that.

Answer (score -1):

Is it appropriate for you to read the whole file and then just parse the string into an array of characters/words?  If so, consider using

`func componentsSeparatedByString(_ separator: String) -> [AnyObject]`

If you know there is a space or comma or whatever separator in between each token, this could be a possible solution.  If that's not acceptable just comment below.

Comment: If I read the question correctly that's what the asker doesn't want to do. Instead they want to read the file a bit at a time.

Comment: Possible to use but it would be very inefficient for huge files. Also sometimes i may want to read first 'x' lines in the list so it won't be efficient for those cases.

Comment: Right, I was just giving OP a workaround, as I'm not sure what he or she is doing with this data.  If they just to perform an operation on each token separated by a comma, it would be okay to parse the whole thing and then iterate through the array.  Granted, it would likely be slower.  EDIT: Just saw your comment.  Yes this is definitely not a good solution then ha.

Comment: Take a look at the [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/) Class reference.  That may be a jumping off point, sorry I don't have more information than that, good luck!