# How to read file into array of Ints

Tags: arrays, swift, bit

In my app documents folder I have a file which I am trying to read byte-per-byte into an array of `UInt8` where each element represents a byte. How would I go about doing this? The file happens to be called Q1.dat.

Here's my unsuccessful attempt:

```
func readArray() -> [Int]? {
    if let arrayPath: String = createArrayPath() {
        if let arrayFromFile: [Int] = NSArray(contentsOfFile: arrayPath) as? [Int] {
            return arrayFromFile
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func createArrayPath () -> String? {
    if let docsPath: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).last {
        return ((docsPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("Q1") as NSString).stringByAppendingPathExtension("dat")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: One of the requirements to posting a proper question on SO is that you provide your best attempt in code. Could you please update with code? Also, review [ask].

Comment: does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581517/read-a-file-url-line-by-line-in-swift

Comment: Do you want an array of 1s and 0s or an array of bytes?

Comment: How was the file created?

Comment: @RomanSausarnes Both would be useful, although either one would still be helpful!

Comment: @Adam It was written in C++, however I don't think it matters since I'm just reading the bits. It could be a mp4 for all intents and purposes

Comment: Do you want each Int to contain a single byte from the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let filePath = "/Path/To/Directory/Q1.dat"

var bytes = [UInt8]()

if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {

    var buffer = [UInt8](count: data.length, repeatedValue: 0)
    data.getBytes(&buffer, length: data.length)
    bytes = buffer
}
```

I'm sorry, I'm not in a place where I can test it, but with a little tinkering it should give you an array of `UInt8`s, each of which represents a byte from the file.

EDIT: And if you really want this to be an array of `Int`s instead of `UInt8`s, just `map` `bytes` to an array of `Int`s:

```
let intBytes = bytes.map { Int($0) }
```

...although generally speaking it is not clear why you want to work with anything other than a collection of bytes, which are most appropriately represented as a series of `UInt8`s.

And if you really, really, want the ones and zeros, then tacking this on to the end should do it:

```
var onesAndZeros = [UInt8]()

bytes.forEach { byte in

    var array = [UInt8](count: 8, repeatedValue: 0)

    let bits = String(byte, radix: 2).characters.flatMap { UInt8(String($0)) }

    array.replaceRange((8-bits.count)..<8, with: bits)
    onesAndZeros.appendContentsOf(array)
}
```

Again, I went with `UInt8` instead of `Int`, just because it makes more sense, but change it up as you need.

Just to neaten things up, you can wrap the two operations in a couple of functions like this:

```
func bytesFromFile(filePath: String) -> [UInt8]? {

    guard let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) else { return nil }

    var buffer = [UInt8](count: data.length, repeatedValue: 0)
    data.getBytes(&buffer, length: data.length)

    return buffer
}

func bitsFromBytes(bytes: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {

    var onesAndZeros = [UInt8]()

    bytes.forEach { byte in

        var array = [UInt8](count: 8, repeatedValue: 0)

        let bits = String(byte, radix: 2).characters.flatMap { UInt8(String($0)) }

        array.replaceRange((8-bits.count)..<8, with: bits)
        onesAndZeros.appendContentsOf(array)
    }

    return onesAndZeros
}
```

Comment: `let intBytes = bytes.map { Int($0) }` converts each single byte to an integer and does not take 4 bytes to form a single UInt32.