# base64 string generated different between swift and c#

Tags: c#, swift, base64

I am trying to generate a base64 string from the same image in swift and c#, come out the base64 string are different but similar, is it suppose the base64 string should be same if generated from the same image?

The base64 string result in swift 
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/..................


The base64 string result in c# 
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/..................


And i have proved that one from swift is invalid base64 string, that one from c# is valid. is it any problem on my swift script? 



//swift

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"a.jpg")!
var strBase64 = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
```

//c#

```
private string GenString()
{
    byte[] bytes = GetFileByteArray(@"C:\temp\a.jpg");

    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}

private byte[] GetFileByteArray(string filename)
{
     FileStream oFileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     byte[] FileByteArrayData = new byte[oFileStream.Length];            
     oFileStream.Read(FileByteArrayData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(oFileStream.Length));
     oFileStream.Close();

     return FileByteArrayData;
}
```

Comment: I suspect UIImage does some re-compression. Does the same approach as in C# (just reading bytes from file) work in Swift?

Comment: How to read bytes from file directly? thanks.

Comment: I'm not proficient with swift, but suppose it goes something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34663223/1353187

Comment: Finally, I got the answer from here. Thanks all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925729/invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This thread is old, but I want to post answers as the existing one is not correct, in my opinion*

The Swift code is doing an extra compression on the original image, unlike directly reading the image file in the C# code. Even though the quality is set to 100%, you may have potentially altered the image data.

I recommend to use `Data` class (Swift bridging equivalent to `NSData`) to read in the image file unaltered, with this constructor specifically: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3126626-init

...then you can get the base-64 string from the `Data` class using `base64EncodedString(options:)`

As for how to retrieve the file path URL, use `Bundle` to locate resources in the app bundle. Assuming your `a.jpg` are simply copied into the app bundle root during build, simply use this method:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1411540-url

```swift
// Swift 5.1
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "a" withExtension:"jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below code to convert your image into Base64 string.

```
    func ImageToBase64String(format: ImageType, image:UIImage) -> String? {
        var imageBase64Data: Data?
        switch format {
        case .png: imageBase64Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        case .jpeg(let compression): imageBase64Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 
        compression)
       }
          return imageBase64Data?.base64EncodedString()
      }

public enum ImageType {
    case png
    case jpeg(CGFloat)
}
```

Calling code for the function

```
    let image = UIImage(named:"name of your image")
    let base64String = ImageToBase64String(format: .png, image: image!)
```

Comment: Same, generated an invalid base64 string... any idea? thanks.