# Filehandle class loading whole file into memory

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to read data from big files sequentially. Since the files can be bigger than the available memory, I don't want the file to be completely loaded into memory.

```swift
class RecordImporter {     

    func `import`(url: URL) {
        guard let reader = RecordReader(url: url) else { return }
        self.resume(from: reader)
    }    

    private func resume(from reader: RecordReader) {
        while let _ = reader.nextData() {

        }
        //Checking memory here is about 300Mb, the test file size.
        return
    }
}
```

```swift
class RecordReader {   

    private var fileHandle: FileHandle

    init?(url: URL) {
        do {
            self.fileHandle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: url)            
        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func nextData() -> Data? {
        let data = self.fileHandle.readData(ofLength: 10000)
        guard !data.isEmpty else { return nil } 
        return data
    }
}
```

After the while loop is done, the memory is about 300Mb, even though I am reading the data in 10Kb chunks.

For some reason the chunks are not being released.

[image]

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: You probably should read each chunk in a local *autoreleasepool.* – Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40576214/1187415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried before wrapping my use of the data in a autoreleasepool, like:

```swift
func nextData() -> Data? {
        let data = autoreleasepool  {
            let data = self.fileHandle.readData(ofLength: 10000)
            guard !data.isEmpty else { return nil } 
            return data 
         }
        return data
    } 
 }
```

What I didn't realize is that is the reading action the one that needs to be inside:

```swift
autoreleasepool  {
 while let data = reader.nextData() {
    print(data.count)
 }              
}
```

This works correctly. Thanks Martin for the hint.