# Swift version of StreamReader only streams the entire file (not in chunks, which is desired)

Tags: ios, swift, stream

I have been having issues processing large files.  At first I was blaming the parser, so I wrote one, but still have the same issues.
If I use this code to scan a 1,000,000 record file (250 MB), it takes up 4 GB of memory while processing. I would expect under 50 MB, considering I am only taking one line at a time:

```
func sample(fileURL: URL) {
  if let aStreamReader = StreamReader(path: fileURL.path) {
      defer {
          aStreamReader.close()
      }
      while let line = aStreamReader.nextLine() {
        // insert industrious code here... (a function call)
      }
  }
}
```

(note this doesn't do anything except read the file and discard the results) **

> Why is the entire file being processed rather than one line at a time?

** The files I need to process range in the many GBs.
I did not write the StreamReader - I have found the same code in a number of places with minor variations -- it appears to be based on a C# class.   This is the StreamReader code I am using:

//  StreamReader.swift

```
import Foundation

class StreamReader {
    let encoding: String.Encoding
    let chunkSize: Int
    var fileHandle: FileHandle!
    let delimData: Data
    var buffer: Data
    var atEof: Bool

    init?(path: String, delimiter: String = "\n", encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8,
          chunkSize: Int = 4096) {

        guard let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: path),
            let delimData = delimiter.data(using: encoding) else {
                return nil
        }
        self.encoding = encoding
        self.chunkSize = chunkSize
        self.fileHandle = fileHandle
        self.delimData = delimData
        self.buffer = Data(capacity: chunkSize)
        self.atEof = false
    }

    deinit {
        self.close()
    }

    /// Return next line, or nil on EOF.
    func nextLine() -> String? {
        precondition(fileHandle != nil, "Attempt to read from closed file")

        // Read data chunks from file until a line delimiter is found:
        while !atEof {
            if let range = buffer.range(of: delimData) {
                // Convert complete line (excluding the delimiter) to a string:
                let line = String(data: buffer.subdata(in: 0..<range.lowerBound), encoding: encoding)
                // Remove line (and the delimiter) from the buffer:
                buffer.removeSubrange(0..<range.upperBound)
                return line
            }
            let tmpData = fileHandle.readData(ofLength: chunkSize)
            if !tmpData.isEmpty {
                buffer.append(tmpData)
            } else {
                // EOF or read error.
                atEof = true
                if !buffer.isEmpty {
                    // Buffer contains last line in file (not terminated by delimiter).
                    let line = String(data: buffer as Data, encoding: encoding)
                    buffer.count = 0
                    return line
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    /// Start reading from the beginning of file.
    func rewind() {
        fileHandle.seek(toFileOffset: 0)
        buffer.count = 0
        atEof = false
    }

    /// Close the underlying file. No reading must be done after calling this method.
    func close() {
        fileHandle?.closeFile()
        fileHandle = nil
    }
}

extension StreamReader : Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<String> {
        return AnyIterator {
            return self.nextLine()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your file actually contain \n characters?

Comment: Excellent catch!  I changed it back to "n" for posting, but in Xcode I see "\r" at the end of the lines (in vim is says (dos) at the bottom of the display), so I replaced "\n" with "\r" and saw the same behavior. Do I need a 2 character sequence?

Comment: I don't want to guess.  In your place, I'd use something like "Hex Fiend", or `od -c` from the terminal, to find out what the actual file bytes were.

Comment: I tried oc -c c2.xml, and it says -bash: oc: command not found

Comment: That was `od`.  :)

Comment: Sorry, been at this since 6:30 this morning... Yes. each line ends with \r  \n. Changed the code to "\r\n" but get exact same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! 1000003 records in under 35 MB (originally: 4GB)
Although the code I was using might have been useful once I solved the encoding issue, I found code I'm more comfortable with. (He even provided a gist.)

See question [Read a file/URL line-by-line in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581517/read-a-file-url-line-by-line-in-swift/24648951#24648951). Specifically the answer from Andy C, which is a modernization of the answer from @algal. Click on the link to see other excellent, thoughtful ideas from Matt and Martin R. (both of which are higher rated than this solution).

Finally, for the lazy ones:

```
import Foundation

/// Reads text file line by line
class LineReader {
    let path: String

    fileprivate let file: UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>!

    init?(path: String) {
        self.path = path

        file = fopen(path, "r")

        guard file != nil else { return nil }

    }

    var nextLine: String? {
        var line:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>? = nil
        var linecap:Int = 0
        defer { free(line) }
        return getline(&line, &linecap, file) > 0 ? String(cString: line!) : nil
    }

    deinit {
        fclose(file)
    }
}

extension LineReader: Sequence {
    func  makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<String> {
        return AnyIterator<String> {
            return self.nextLine
        }
    }
}
```