# Swift: Most performant way of parsing 10k lines of data?

Tags: json, swift, protocol-buffers, flatbuffers

So my app is currently reading 10k lines into a variable and then using SwiftyJson to parse it into realm.

**Source**: 
https://github.com/skishore/makemeahanzi/blob/master/graphics.txt
https://github.com/skishore/makemeahanzi/blob/master/dictionary.txt

**Problem**: It takes way too long: *2:28minutes*. Also it takes *400mb of memory*!

**Question**: How to make this faster?
Any of you having experience with [Flatbuffers](https://github.com/mzaks/FlatBuffersSwift) or [Protobuf](https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf)?

Help would be very welcome!

Cheers, Dom

---

This is the code:

```
func parseToRealm() {

    // each of these files have 9500+ lines of data
    // (basically dictionaries with word definitions)
    let graphicsFileContents = readFile_Graphics()
    let dictFileContents = readFile_Dict()

    // check if counts of two source files match
    if (graphicsFileContents.count == dictFileContents.count && graphicsFileContents.count > 1 && dictFileContents.count > 1) {
        var i = 0
        // make empty array of characters
        var characterArr = [Characters()]

        // loop through two files to get all chars
        for jsonString in graphicsFileContents {
            // parse data from string into json
            let dataFromString = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
            let singleCharJson = try? JSON(data: dataFromString!)


            // parse stuff from file1
            // ... deleted lines for legal reasons


            // DICT information
            let dictDataFromString = dictFileContents[i].data(using: .utf8)
            let singleDictJson = try? JSON(data: dictDataFromString!)

            // parse stuff from that dictionary
            // ... deleted lines for legal reasons

            characterArr.append(Character)

            // Every x characters, write them into DB
            if (i % 150 == 0 || i == graphicsFileContents.count){
                realmActions.writeCharsToRealm(characterArr: characterArr)
                print("Writing \(i)-\(i + 150)")
                // reset array to safe memory
                characterArr = [Characters()]
            }
            i+=1
        } // end loop file contents
    }else{
        print ("two files have different counts of lines. aborting...")
    }
}


// read graphics file and return all contents as array of strings
        // return Array of Strings
        func readFile_Graphics () -> [String] {
            // predeclare emtpy string array
            var myStrings = [String]()
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "graphics", ofType: "txt") {
                do {
                    let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
                     myStrings = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
                } catch {
                    print("cannot get file graphics.txt. Error message:")
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            return myStrings
        }



// read dictionary file and return all contents as array of strings
    func readFile_Dict () -> [String]{
        var myStrings = [""]
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dictionary", ofType: "txt") {
            do {
                let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
                myStrings = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
            } catch {
                print("cannot get file dictionary.txt. Error message:")
                print(error)
            }
        }
    return myStrings
    }
```

Comment: You are splitting to lines and then decoding as JSON? I don't understand. Why not a single JSON? Why not `Decodable` instead of SwiftyJSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "graphics", ofType: "txt") else {
                print("Dang! File wasn't found!")
                return
            }
            let cal = Calendar.current
            let d1 = Date()

            guard let streamReader = StreamReader(path: path) else {
                print("Dang! StreamReader couldn't be created!")
                return
            }
            var counter = 0
            while !streamReader.atEof {
                guard let nextLine = streamReader.nextLine() else {
                    print("Oops! Reached the end before printing!")
                    break
                }
                let json = JSON(parseJSON: nextLine)

                counter += 1
                print("\(counter): \(nextLine)")
            }
            let d2 = Date() 
            let components = cal.dateComponents([.minute], from: d2, to: d1)
            print("Diff: \(components.minute!)")
        }
    }
```

[Stream Reader class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648951/2299040)

```
import Foundation

class StreamReader  {

    let encoding : String.Encoding
    let chunkSize : Int
    var fileHandle : FileHandle!
    let delimData : Data
    var buffer : Data
    var atEof : Bool

    init?(path: String, delimiter: String = "\n", encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8,
          chunkSize: Int = 4096) {

        guard let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: path),
            let delimData = delimiter.data(using: encoding) else {
                return nil
        }
        self.encoding = encoding
        self.chunkSize = chunkSize
        self.fileHandle = fileHandle
        self.delimData = delimData
        self.buffer = Data(capacity: chunkSize)
        self.atEof = false
    }

    deinit {
        self.close()
    }

    /// Return next line, or nil on EOF.
    func nextLine() -> String? {
        precondition(fileHandle != nil, "Attempt to read from closed file")

        // Read data chunks from file until a line delimiter is found:
        while !atEof {
            if let range = buffer.range(of: delimData) {
                // Convert complete line (excluding the delimiter) to a string:
                let line = String(data: buffer.subdata(in: 0..<range.lowerBound), encoding: encoding)
                // Remove line (and the delimiter) from the buffer:
                buffer.removeSubrange(0..<range.upperBound)
                return line
            }
            let tmpData = fileHandle.readData(ofLength: chunkSize)
            if tmpData.count > 0 {
                buffer.append(tmpData)
            } else {
                // EOF or read error.
                atEof = true
                if buffer.count > 0 {
                    // Buffer contains last line in file (not terminated by delimiter).
                    let line = String(data: buffer as Data, encoding: encoding)
                    buffer.count = 0
                    return line
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    /// Start reading from the beginning of file.
    func rewind() -> Void {
        fileHandle.seek(toFileOffset: 0)
        buffer.count = 0
        atEof = false
    }

    /// Close the underlying file. No reading must be done after calling this method.
    func close() -> Void {
        fileHandle?.closeFile()
        fileHandle = nil
    }
}

extension StreamReader : Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<String> {
        return AnyIterator {
            return self.nextLine()
        }
    }
}
```

The StreamReader class reads the text file line by line so no need to read the whole file at once. the first block reads the content of the file. Try the above code. this should solve your problem. please note that I've used background thread whereas the realm doesn't work on background thread (AFAIK). let me know if that helps.

Comment: I appreciate it bro, I will definitely take a look at it! From the first look it looks very promising...

Comment: WOW! So, status report: On mac it took only 46 seconds for all 10k lines, and I was astounded! But then on the iphone6 it took 2:30mins. On both machines it took about 200MB memory "only". So the time is about the same, just memory is cut in half... Writing the stuff into realm isnt working yet because I use a background thread.. Is there any way to pass back the populated array after the async thread is finished?

Comment: @ItsMeDom, I don't have much exp with Realm. will try this weekend and let you know about it

Comment: So I made it work: *creating a new realm instance* did the trick. On macbook the threading makes it way faster (74secs). On the iphone6 it still takes the same time though. Probably its the CPU...  Thanks mate. Accepted your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @ItsMeDom, creating a new instance is not good. I've been reading Realm this weekend and found that Realm Transactions is what you are looking for. You need to look in to Transactions.. this way it should minimize the time as much as possible . have a look at following code: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2857#issuecomment-395432162 it's in Java but can easily translate to Swift.

Comment: you sure? I am almost 100% sure that while writing to realm(takes about 20secs) the user wont be accessing realm otherwise.... But okay, I'll have a look!