CallDirectory Extension killed because using too much memory
I often get the following error when doing a read of a json file with more than 30,000 elements:
The app “call direction extension” has been killed by the operating system because it is using too much memory.
Before that, it worked fine with about 20,000 elements
This is my code:
public func readReportFile () -> [ReportModel] {
let fileURL = self.reportStoreUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("json")
// 1. Read the file data
do {
  let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: fileURL)
  let data = try fileHandle.readToEnd()
  fileHandle.closeFile()
  // 2. Check if data is valid
  guard let jsonData = data else {
    print("Error: Could not read data from file")
    return []
  }
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  do {
    let decodedData = try decoder.decode([ReportModel].self, from: jsonData)
    return decodedData
  } catch {
    print("Error: Could not parse JSON data: \(error)")
    return []
  }
} catch {
  print("Error: Could not open file at \(fileURL): \(error)")
}
return []

}
Please help me improve my code, I also tried chunk size, but it doesn't seem to work as expected and the memory error still occurs. In the future this number may reach 50,000 elements.
Many thanks!

Don't read the whole file into memory. Don't use json. If it is a call blocking extension you could use a simple text file with one number per line or even write the integer bytes to the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581517/read-a-file-url-line-by-line-in-swift for some approaches.

@Paulw11, many thanks, my file also has keys like: 'name', 'number', can I use the file?

I'm using identification extension

Ok.  You can still just a text file of number, name\n avoid the JSON and read it a line at a time

So the algorithm like your example above would be:

read line by line
parse before the "," sign is number, after "," is name.
Is it accurate?


yes.  That is correct
